# Error on slicing array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem with slicing an array. The problem is that if I do some operation inside of function and return modified array my array outside of function is also changed.
I could not really understand that behavior of numpy slicing opration on array.

Here is the code:

```python
import numpy as np

def do_smth(a):

    x = np.concatenate((a[..., 1], a[..., 3]))
    y = np.concatenate((a[..., 2], a[..., 4]))
    xmin, xmax = np.floor(min(x)), np.ceil(max(x))
    ymin, ymax = np.floor(min(y)), np.ceil(max(y))

    a[..., 1:3] = a[...,1:3] - np.array([xmin, ymin])
    a[..., 3:5] = a[...,3:5] - np.array([xmin, ymin])
    return a

def main():
        old_a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
                          [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                          [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

       new_a = do_smth(old_a)
       print "new_a:\n", new_a, '\n\n'
       print "old_a:\n", old_a
```

gives output:

```
new_a:
[[ 0  0  0  2  2]
 [ 5  5  5  7  7]
 [10 10 10 12 12]]

old_a:
[[ 0  0  0  2  2]
 [ 5  5  5  7  7]
 [10 10 10 12 12]]
```

Can anyone tell why `old_a` has been changed? And how can I make `old_a` unchanged?
Thank you

Comment: What is `a` in this line `new_a = do_smth(a)`? If it is `old_a` what you are seeing is expected. Because when you pass `old_a` you are passing the reference to the outer list and not the copy.

Comment: `old_a` changes because the same object is referenced inside and outside the function. To avoid it, pass a copy.

Comment: try new_a=do_smth(a.copy())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not slicing the array, but the fact that numpy arrays are mutable objects.

This means that, whenever you make something like

```python
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = a
```

the object `b` is a view of array `a`, more precisely, `b` is just another name for `a`.

Note that, when you pass a mutable python object (like a python list or dict) to a function
that do some operation that changes this object, the original object passed is also changed.
This is how python (not only numpy) treats mutable objects.

to get the feeling you can do something like this:

```python
from __future__ import print_funtion
import numpy as np

a = np.ones(3)
b = a

c = [1,1,1]
d = c

print("a before:", a) 
print("b before:", b)
print("c before:", c) 
print("c before:", d)
def change_it(x):
    x[0] = 10

change_it(a)
change_it(c)
print("a after:", a) 
print("b after:", b)
print("c after:", c) 
print("c after:", d)
```

which gives:

```
a before: [ 1.  1.  1.]
b before: [ 1.  1.  1.]
c before: [1, 1, 1]
d before: [1, 1, 1]
a after: [ 10.   1.   1.]
b after: [ 10.   1.   1.]
c after: [10, 1, 1]
d after: [10, 1, 1]
```

Note that the function `change_it` doesn't even return anything and was only used 
on `a` and `c` but also changed `b` and `d`

If you want to avoid this, you must use an explicit copy of your array.

That is easily done by:

```python
def do_smth(original_a):  # change the argument name

    a = original_a.copy()  # make an explicit copy
    x = np.concatenate((a[..., 1], a[..., 3]))
    y = np.concatenate((a[..., 2], a[..., 4]))
    xmin, xmax = np.floor(min(x)), np.ceil(max(x))
    ymin, ymax = np.floor(min(y)), np.ceil(max(y))

    a[..., 1:3] = a[...,1:3] - np.array([xmin, ymin])
    a[..., 3:5] = a[...,3:5] - np.array([xmin, ymin])
    return a
```

Answer (score 2):

Although values in Python are passed by assignment, the object you are sending in is actually a reference to a memory location.  So thus, when you change the object in the function you are altering the same variable you sent into the function.

You will want to clone the object first, and then do your operations on the copy.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but this is confusing. Each time using copy() is not a way of doing professional programming (I think so). Is there any equivalent procedure on that?

Comment: I can't think of a way of having two unique copies of the same data without cloning it...so really this isn't going to have any more memory overhead than what he expected it to do.  Also, how would cloning the object be non-professional?

Comment: I agree with copy()/clone  something. Here, the problem is that some changes inside of the function causes some changes outside which should not behave like that. My point was it is not the case (I think so). Because, imagine that I do huge process with various functions in which I can do anything I want, but outside I do something very different. Here, the problem comes... I can not put something like copy() everytime.. That's what I wanted to say by "not professional". What would you think?

Comment: Although I understand your reluctance to want to clone the object every time (which can be done through the constructor of most collections), this is just the way it is unfortunately.  Like Java, Python sends all it's objects to functions by value.  For objects (i.e. anything other than primitive data types like int, char, float, double, boolean, etc) the "value" of the object is it's location in memory.  So that value is a pointer, and unfortunately the value will be modified in the calling function too.

Comment: However, if you were to use an immutable type, or modify the slicing algorithm to make a copy of the object being sliced and then return the modified copy from the function copy, leaving the original unscathed.  Or better yet, make the slicing algorithm build a new list from the values as it cuts pieces out of it.  It would be less memory efficient, but then it wouldn't modify the original object.  I'm sure you could extend the class this guy is using and override the slice function with your own.  Heck, just override it, create a copy, and then call the base class's slice function on it.